# Graphviz, no rankdir

Tags: graphviz

this graph is generated by a program, I didn't type this (I don't want anyone thinking I would, this format is so ... artificial)

```
digraph G {
     rankdir=LR
     n0_0_ [label = "[0, 0]"]
     n0_0_  ->  n0_0_
     n0_1_ [label = "[0, 1]"]
     n0_0_  ->  n0_1_
     n0_1_  ->  n0_0_
     n1_0_ [label = "[1, 0]"]
     n0_0_  ->  n1_0_
     n1_0_  ->  n0_0_
     n1_1_ [label = "[1, 1]"]
     n0_0_  ->  n1_1_
     n1_1_  ->  n0_0_
}
```

Graphviz has put [0,0] on the left, and everything else on the right, the next rank.

It'd make far more sense however to have [0,0] in the centre and the remaining 3 nodes around it.

The arc from [0,0] to itself will be omitted, it is important for the application that graphviz does not try and structure it with ranks, lovely symmetry should develop, why I don't expect graphviz to see it and exploit it, the methods it uses (energy methods on springs IIRC) should create the right form!

How do I say "there is no rankdir" or something to that effect? Is a bi-product of digraph?

**edit**

No it is not a biproduct of digraph, as you can see with this one, I suppose another way to say the goal of this would be "no crossing edges", the graphs are planar.

```
graph G {
     n0_0_ [label = "[0, 0]"]
     n0_0_  --  n0_0_
     n0_1_ [label = "[0, 1]"]
     n0_0_  --  n0_1_
     n0_1_  --  n0_2_
     n0_2_  --  n0_3_
     n0_3_  --  n0_4_
     n0_4_  --  n0_0_
     n0_2_ [label = "[0, 2]"]
     n0_0_  --  n0_2_
     n0_2_  --  n0_4_
     n0_4_  --  n0_1_
     n0_1_  --  n0_3_
     n0_3_  --  n0_0_
     n0_3_ [label = "[0, 3]"]
     n0_0_  --  n0_3_
     n0_3_  --  n0_1_
     n0_1_  --  n0_4_
     n0_4_  --  n0_2_
     n0_2_  --  n0_0_
     n0_4_ [label = "[0, 4]"]
     n0_0_  --  n0_4_
     n0_4_  --  n0_3_
     n0_3_  --  n0_2_
     n0_2_  --  n0_1_
     n0_1_  --  n0_0_
     n1_0_ [label = "[1, 0]"]
     n0_0_  --  n1_0_
     n1_0_  --  n2_0_
     n2_0_  --  n3_0_
     n3_0_  --  n4_0_
     n4_0_  --  n0_0_
     n1_1_ [label = "[1, 1]"]
     n0_0_  --  n1_1_
     n1_1_  --  n2_2_
     n2_2_  --  n3_3_
     n3_3_  --  n4_4_
     n4_4_  --  n0_0_
     n1_2_ [label = "[1, 2]"]
     n0_0_  --  n1_2_
     n1_2_  --  n2_4_
     n2_4_  --  n3_1_
     n3_1_  --  n4_3_
     n4_3_  --  n0_0_
     n1_3_ [label = "[1, 3]"]
     n0_0_  --  n1_3_
     n1_3_  --  n2_1_
     n2_1_  --  n3_4_
     n3_4_  --  n4_2_
     n4_2_  --  n0_0_
     n1_4_ [label = "[1, 4]"]
     n0_0_  --  n1_4_
     n1_4_  --  n2_3_
     n2_3_  --  n3_2_
     n3_2_  --  n4_1_
     n4_1_  --  n0_0_
     n2_0_ [label = "[2, 0]"]
     n0_0_  --  n2_0_
     n2_0_  --  n4_0_
     n4_0_  --  n1_0_
     n1_0_  --  n3_0_
     n3_0_  --  n0_0_
     n2_1_ [label = "[2, 1]"]
     n0_0_  --  n2_1_
     n2_1_  --  n4_2_
     n4_2_  --  n1_3_
     n1_3_  --  n3_4_
     n3_4_  --  n0_0_
     n2_2_ [label = "[2, 2]"]
     n0_0_  --  n2_2_
     n2_2_  --  n4_4_
     n4_4_  --  n1_1_
     n1_1_  --  n3_3_
     n3_3_  --  n0_0_
     n2_3_ [label = "[2, 3]"]
     n0_0_  --  n2_3_
     n2_3_  --  n4_1_
     n4_1_  --  n1_4_
     n1_4_  --  n3_2_
     n3_2_  --  n0_0_
     n2_4_ [label = "[2, 4]"]
     n0_0_  --  n2_4_
     n2_4_  --  n4_3_
     n4_3_  --  n1_2_
     n1_2_  --  n3_1_
     n3_1_  --  n0_0_
     n3_0_ [label = "[3, 0]"]
     n0_0_  --  n3_0_
     n3_0_  --  n1_0_
     n1_0_  --  n4_0_
     n4_0_  --  n2_0_
     n2_0_  --  n0_0_
     n3_1_ [label = "[3, 1]"]
     n0_0_  --  n3_1_
     n3_1_  --  n1_2_
     n1_2_  --  n4_3_
     n4_3_  --  n2_4_
     n2_4_  --  n0_0_
     n3_2_ [label = "[3, 2]"]
     n0_0_  --  n3_2_
     n3_2_  --  n1_4_
     n1_4_  --  n4_1_
     n4_1_  --  n2_3_
     n2_3_  --  n0_0_
     n3_3_ [label = "[3, 3]"]
     n0_0_  --  n3_3_
     n3_3_  --  n1_1_
     n1_1_  --  n4_4_
     n4_4_  --  n2_2_
     n2_2_  --  n0_0_
     n3_4_ [label = "[3, 4]"]
     n0_0_  --  n3_4_
     n3_4_  --  n1_3_
     n1_3_  --  n4_2_
     n4_2_  --  n2_1_
     n2_1_  --  n0_0_
     n4_0_ [label = "[4, 0]"]
     n0_0_  --  n4_0_
     n4_0_  --  n3_0_
     n3_0_  --  n2_0_
     n2_0_  --  n1_0_
     n1_0_  --  n0_0_
     n4_1_ [label = "[4, 1]"]
     n0_0_  --  n4_1_
     n4_1_  --  n3_2_
     n3_2_  --  n2_3_
     n2_3_  --  n1_4_
     n1_4_  --  n0_0_
     n4_2_ [label = "[4, 2]"]
     n0_0_  --  n4_2_
     n4_2_  --  n3_4_
     n3_4_  --  n2_1_
     n2_1_  --  n1_3_
     n1_3_  --  n0_0_
     n4_3_ [label = "[4, 3]"]
     n0_0_  --  n4_3_
     n4_3_  --  n3_1_
     n3_1_  --  n2_4_
     n2_4_  --  n1_2_
     n1_2_  --  n0_0_
     n4_4_ [label = "[4, 4]"]
     n0_0_  --  n4_4_
     n4_4_  --  n3_3_
     n3_3_  --  n2_2_
     n2_2_  --  n1_1_
     n1_1_  --  n0_0_
}
```

It really does not express this nicely.

`ordering=out` helped, but there are still very clearly ranks

Comment: For your first example, simply using `neato` instead of `dot` should be doing the trick - or am i missing something?

Comment: circo worked, thanks @marapet

Comment: @AlecTeal Seems like marapet gave an answer you should mark as answer

Comment: @Jens my question is TL;DR tbh. 100 views / year is probably mostly indexers

Comment: @AlecTeal well I was looking for unanswered GraphViz questions and yours came up but was infact answered

Answer (score 2):

`dot` is supposed to work for directed graphs and uses ranking of nodes.

Other layouts such as `neato` or `circo` or `sfdp` may yield better results in your case.